# Flashpoints to start for fresh lvl 50's

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Soon our guild will get together the first 4-man group of lvl 50 characters.
What order would be be good to run the Flashpoints and nightmare Flashpoints in?

Comment: "Best" is entirely subjective, and I'm not sure this question can be made anything but a recommendation.

Comment: are you most interested in story or gear?

Comment: just looking for flashpoints that can be completed with mostly leveling gear. We did Black Talon Nightmare today which was pretty easy for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo, after a few other hardmode Flashpoints I can say that Black Talon is definitely the easiest one.
No problem at all beating it with with leveling gear and a few crafted items.

Other Flashpoints are much more of a challenge.